# java, putting priority of objects into an array by its self, then reassigning the sorted priority to correct objects HW

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to figure out a way to reassign priorities to each respected object after I have sorted them.

Each object gets a priority from the user using setters. I then make an Int Array using the getPriorities so I can sort them.

```
     Food[] list = new Food[3];

    int[] priorityArray = {(int) ((Fruit) list[0]).getPriority(), (int) ((Fruit) list[1]).getPriority(), (int) ((Meat) list[2]).getPriority() };
```

After I sort the array of priority ints, how can I reassign each priority to the correct object? I turned the getPriorities into regular ints when I made the array.

I'd sort the priorities straight by getPriorities, like this:

```
        Food temp;
    System.out.println("\nsorted list:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {


       for (int j = 1; j < (list.length - i); j++)  {
           if (((Fruit) list[j-1]).getPriority() > ((Fruit) list[j]).getPriority()||((Fruit) list[j-1]).getPriority() > ((Meat) list[j]).getPriority()||((Meat) list[j-1]).getPriority() > ((Fruit) list[j]).getPriority()||((Meat) list[j-1]).getPriority() > ((Meat) list[j]).getPriority()) 


           {
            temp = list[j - 1];
            list[j - 1] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;

           }
       }    


       System.out.println(list[i]);
```

But I get errors when I do this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: homework4.orange cannot be cast to homework4.Meat at homework4.main4.main(main4.java:114)

Comment: Are you tyring to sort the list of Fruit according to priority?

Comment: its a list of Food, both made of Fruit (extends Food) and Meat (also extends Food).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement, you have

```
 ((Meat) list[j]).getPriority()
```

When j = 1, you are type casting a Fruit object into a Meat object. This is throwing the error.

Is it possible to remove the type casts in the if statement? It seems like the getPriority() method could be placed into the Food class and overriden if needed.

Comment: I created an auto getPriority via Source in Food Abstract class and replaced my IF statement with (list[j-1].getPriority() > list[j].getPriority());

This works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should implement custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and sort list by priority as

`Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());`.

Comment: With respect to the hw, probably just implement compareTo()

Comment: Probably the object `Fruit` can be used in the different context and I think that sorting by priority is not a primary sorting.

Comment: I am getting an error when I try this:  "The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Food[], MyComparator)"

Comment: @user2803251 You need to create new class `MyComparator` and implement it or extends your class from `Comparable` and override equals, hashcode functions.

Comment: I did that:  import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyComparator {
 class priorityComparator implements Comparator<Food> {
     @Override
     public int compare(Food a, Food b) {
         return a.priority < b.priority ? -1 : a.priority == b.priority ? 0 : 1;
     }

  
}

Comment: It should be `public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Food> {...}`